# Problema ao ligar servidor NextJS - React

Tags: react, next.js

Estou com problemas para iniciar o servidor no NEXT JS.

Ao iniciar o npm run dev, ele começa a inicializar o servidor mas segundos depois de aparecer "-info..." como mostra a imagem ele encerra.

Soluções que tentei:
Reiniciar pc, Criar projeto novo, Instalar novamente o nodejs, resetar cache do nextjs, excluir modules e usar o npm install novamente.

Uma questão é que o react-create-app, vite, nuxtJs ou django consigo rodar o servidor sem problemas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]